# How to show errors inside a form on submit in angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation

I have the following form, ts script and error message for validation:

```
<form [formGroup]="tripForm" (ngSubmit)="addTrip(tripForm)" novalidate> 
    <div class="form-group">    
        <label class="control-label">Trip Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="newTripName" name="newTripName" formControlName="newTripName">

        <div *ngIf="tripForm.controls['newTripName'].errors && (tripForm.controls['newTripName'].dirty || tripForm.controls['newTripName'].touched)">
            <div class="error_message" *ngIf="tripForm.controls['newTripName'].errors.required">
                    <span class="e_arrow"></span>
                    <i>Please enter Trip Name</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tripForm = new FormGroup ({
      newTripName: new FormControl('', {
        validators:  Validators.compose([
          Validators.required        
        ]),      
        updateOn: 'blur'
      })
    });   
  }

addTrip(tripForm:NgForm) {    
    if (!tripForm.valid) {        
      return;
    }
}
```

The validation works fine on blur event but the problem is that the validation should also work on submit.
The method isvalid return false but I'm not sure how to show the error message.
As you can see I'm showing message only when the form field is either dirty or touch which is not the case when the form is submitted.

Any idea what should be changed/added to the code above to make it form on submit as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Just manually set the form to touched on submit

Comment: you should make submit button enable on successful validation

Comment: just add ``[disabled]='!tripForm.valid'`` to your button which is of type submit . it will keep your button disabled until the form is valid .

Comment: Touched is a readonly field. As for the disable the submit button, I know about this solution but I'm not able to determine that the form is valid at this stage as I'm planning to do more validation is the sever side.

Comment: You can try markAsDirty() and/or markasTouched() functions available in FormGroup.

Comment: Just give reference to your form like `<form [formGroup]="tripForm" (ngSubmit)="addTrip(tripForm)" #myForm="ngForm" novalidate>` and add the condition in OR part like `myForm.submitted`

Comment: Shameless plug here: using ngx-valdemort would allow you to do that in a much easier way: https://ngx-valdemort.ninja-squad.com